# What builds up a comparator?

Tags: comparator

I'm trying to understand how [comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/comparator) (used in 555 timer) able to compare two voltages.

I'm searching for [comparator schemantics](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=comparator+schematic&biw=1280&bih=677&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRt5XZsqPcAhUSF4gKHQ58Cm4Q_AUICigB) but all I get is the triangle symbol.

AND gate has a symbol "D", and if I search for "[AND gate schemantics](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=and+gate+schematics&biw=1280&bih=677&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbo4Gcs6PcAhUVMt4KHcFyDC4Q_AUICigB)" It'll show me [two transistors](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/log43.gif) that builds up an AND gate.

What builds up a comparator?

Comment: An open loop high gain amplifier

Answer (score 3):

> What builds up a Comparator?

Many data sheets contain semi-idealized details of their internal circuitry such as the ubiquitous LM339: -

[image]

You could probably model this up using a sim and it will give adequate results.

Try reading a few data sheets. Here's the LM311 for instance: -

[image]

And [this link](http://elektronik.emperial.dk/comp.htm) may help you understand them a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

Comparators are fundamentally similar to op-amps, there is a differential input stage followed by one or more single ended amplification stages. The differences are.

1. Comparators don't have to worry about controlling the frequency response to provide stability.
2. Comparators are designed to tolerate running in saturation, since that is where they will spend most of their time.
3. Comparators often have open collector outputs.

So how do they work, lets look at the LM339 simplified schematic that Andy posted.

[image]

Each input has a pair of PNP transitors (other designs may use a single BJT or FET and/or my turn the design upside down to use N type devices but the principle is the same). These try to steer the current down whichever branch has the lower input voltage.

At the bottom of both branches is a "current mirror". This tries to make the current in it's right hand branch match the current in it's left hand branch.

When in+ is higher than in- more current is steered down the right hand branch. However the current mirror limits the current in it's right hand branch to match that in it's left hand branch. The rest of the current flows through the base of the next transistor turning it on. This in turn pulls the base of the output transistor to ground turning it off. An external pull-up will then pull the output high.

When in+ is lower than in- more current is steered down the left hand branch. The current mirror tries (and fails) to make the current in it's right hand branch match that in it's left hand branch. In doing so it pulls the base of the next stage low turning off the transistor. This allows current to flow from the right hand current source into the base of the output transistor turning it on and pulling the output low.

Answer (score 1):

The designer of that Legendary 555 timer wrote a free ebook about designing circuits. You can download it for free at [Designing Analog Chips](http://www.designinganalogchips.com/)

On page 127 (or 9-1) of that book comparators are explained!

Here is a simple example of a comparator straight from that Ebook:

[image]

I know Q3 looks funny but it is actually a current mirror with the input connected to the collector of Q1.

The "bit that does the magic" is really the differential pair Q1 and Q2, Q4 is there to increase the gain of the comparator.

The Ebook will show you loads of basic circuits used in chips. If you're interested in that it is a good read.